# SPFX Question Is it possible to include a custom font reference by extending the toolchain?

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I have a custom font, I include it in the bundle and add it to the dist folder, but the js reference is still linking to its original location. Any ideas? [

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using an import instead of url so the module resolution pre processor can pick it up?

Comment: Yes, I put an import in the sass and nothing. I believe that the problem is in the order in which it is executed, first the sass goes and then the webpack runs. Thanks

Comment: I took the time to open an older project (1.4.1) and I noticed the only difference is that it's using relative paths. So instead of `url('/fonts/myfont.ttf')` I have `url('./fonts/myfont.ttf')` (notice the .)
Also, which version of SPFX is your project on?

Comment: The version is 1.5. and in the gulpfile add this code build.configureWebpack.mergeConfig({
    additionalConfiguration: (generatedConfiguration) => {
      generatedConfiguration.module.rules.push(        
        { test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'] },
        { test: /\.woff2(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, use: { loader: 'file-loader'  } },
        { test: /\.woff(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,  use: { loader: 'file-loader' }
          },
          { test: /\.[ot]tf$/, use: {loader: 'file-loader' } } );
return generatedConfiguration;
    }
  });

Comment: It should work by default without needing you to override the webpack configuration. What if you comment it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adrian,

I was able to resolve this issue with the exception of WOFF2 fonts. Here is how I did it.

1. Upload the font files in the same folder as the .SCSS file. For simplicity, I kept the font files in the same folder as the SCSS, but once you can prove it works, feel free to move the files anywhere you'd like.
2. Include the @font-face definition in your SCSS. For this example, I used Google Webfont's generated SCSS:

   ```
   @font-face {
       font-family: 'Aclonica';
       font-style: normal;
       font-weight: 400;
       src: url('./aclonica-v8-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
       src: local('Aclonica Regular'), local('Aclonica-Regular'),
       url('./aclonica-v8-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       //  url('./aclonica-v8-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('./aclonica-v8-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('./aclonica-v8-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('./aclonica-v8-latin-regular.svg#Aclonica') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
   }
   ```
3. Note that I commented out the **woff2** font. This is the only one that would require messing with webpack and gulp, which I didn't want to do.

That is all you need to do.

Bonus tip: I noticed from your code sample that you only specify the TTF font file. You can use http://font2web.com/ to convert your custom TTF to webfonts if you want broader browser support.

I hope this helps?

Comment: I try it and I tell you something

Answer (score 2):

a bit late but to resolve the woff2 issue, simply add a file called copy-static-assets.json to your config/ folder with the following contents:

```
{
  "includeExtensions": [
    "woff2"
  ]
}
```

this will copy woff2 files to the lib/ output folder which should resolve the error.